# Why do scala org.joda.time.DateTime.parse truncate at millis value in the given date?

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to parse some given date string:

```
val strDate = "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000999+00:00"
val dateFormatter = forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ").withOffsetParsed()
val date = parse(strDate, dateFormatter)
```

but `println(date)` outputs `2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` and
`dateFormatter.print(date)` returns `2014-01-01T00:00:00.000000+00:00`.

I don't understand why the parser only gets 3 fraction of second digits instead of 6 as specified. Can someone explain this ?

EDIT: as @Jesper pointed out, the precision is limited to milliseconds.

Comment: Think about it. Milliseconds = 1/1000ths of a second. How can that have more than 3 digits? 6 digits = microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Right, I meant fraction of second, obviously...

Comment: Joda's `DateTime` class does not allow finer precision than milliseconds, as you can see in the [API docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). So, unfortunately, you won't be able to store microseconds in a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime` class, you'll see that the time is encoded as:

```
/** The millis from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z */
private volatile long iMillis;
```

That the degree of precision you want can be stored via Joda.

The alternative is to use JSR-310.

- if you have Java 8, it's already included.
- add a dependency to `threeten`, then backport for older Java versions.

The base class is Instant which has a nanosecond precision, see: https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/bp/Instant.java